# Why does UIView:animateWithDuration complete immediately?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I have a subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` with the following method which I run on iOS 4:

```
- (void)animate {
    [UIView
     animateWithDuration: 3.0
     delay:1.0
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
     animations:^{
         CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = 
             CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self coordinate].latitude + 0.001,
                                        [self coordinate].longitude + 0.001);
         [self setCoordinate:loc];

     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         NSLog(@"Is completed");
     }];
}
```

It is called by clicking a `UIBarButtonItem`.

I expect to see the my annotation travel across a `MKMapView`. However all I see is the annotation in its final resting place when I call the method like this:

```
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
[myAnnotation animate];
[myAnnotation release];
```

The intended animation only occurs if I call the method like this:

```
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
[myAnnotation performSelector:@selector(animate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
[myAnnotation release];
```

Note that I get the unintended behavior if the 'afterDelay', is smaller e.g. < 0.1s.

Any ideas why this could be the case?

Comment: Is the coordinate property automatically animated? I have not worked with MapKit but not all properties are animatable automatically.

Comment: I don't think the coordinate property is automatically animated per se, but I believe the implementation  of `MKPointAnnotation` must wire into an animatable property of `UIView` as the animation actually works really well if I call the `animate` method using `performSelector` with a big enough value for `afterDelay`.

Comment: I get the same problem when I use the traditional non-blocks animation. I still haven't found an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation ultimately acts on the `MKAnnotationView`, not the `MKAnnotation`. Adding an annotation to a `MKMapView` does not necessarily mean that the corresponding view will be added any time soon.

Therefore you get crazy behaviour if you attempt to animate a MKAnnotation before its corresponding `MKAnnotationView` has been added to the `MKMapView`.

The solution is to only animate a MKAnnotation once you know its corresponding MKAnnotationView has been added to MKView. You can know this by using `MKMapViewDelegate` `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views` to trigger your animation.