# ipad: why does the first animation of my sequential animations always complete immediately?

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, sequential

Similar to SO question ref: [Why does UIView:animateWithDuration complete immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869954/why-does-uiviewanimatewithduration-complete-immediately) however, my code is using [UIView beginAnimation], etc.

I have essentially this:

```
[UIView beginAnimation ...];
[UIView setAnimationDelay: 0.0];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.25];
animatedImage.transform = "scale-up transform";

[UIView setAnimationDelay: 1.25]
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.50];
animatedImage.transform = "scale-down transform";

[UIView commitAnimation];
```

The image immediately jumps to the scale-up size, then 1.25 seconds later it animates nicely to the "scale-down" size.  If I chain more sequences, they all work correctly, except the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put animations in the same beginAnimation zone, they'll animate at the same time.

By calling [UIView setAnimationDelay: 1.25], you're only overwriting your earlier [UIView setAnimationDelay: 0.0].

So what happens, is that the UIView is told to scale both up and down simultaneously. I guess since you tell it to scale both up and down, it simply skips the to the last of the animations, but you did tell it to scale up, so it does that without animating.

I suggest using the block syntax in stead, it allows you to do things after an animation completes:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.25
                 animations:^{animatedImage.transform = "scale-up transform";}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.25
                                      animations:^{animatedImage.transform = "scale-down transform";}
                     ];
                 }
 ];
```

The code in the completion block (the ^{code} constructions are called 'blocks') is what happens after the first animation. You can keep chaining this for as many animations as you like.

(BOOL finished) is a parameter passed along with the block. It tells if the animation was really finished. If NO, your animation was interrupted.

Comment: Is this functionally the same as having nested beginAnimations? Because I tried that and had the same failure.  Meanwhile, I will try your suggestion and get back to you (thanks for the quick response).

Comment: If you use two seperate beginAnimations, The second one will stop the first one. Delay in the second one might work, never tested that, but I think using beginAnimationsWithDuration is better anyway, since you can set the duration. The completion is also more stable than working with delays and there's another version of beginAnimations with even more parameters that lets you set special options on your animation.

Comment: Sorry that isn't what I meant.  The doc says that you can nest [UIView beginAnimation] [UIView beginAnimation [UIView commitAnimation] [UIView commitAnimation].  Is that equiv to your code?

Comment: @mobibob Ah... I've never seen that before, no idea if it works. I always used animateWithDuration: anyway, since I found out how it works~.

Comment: I now see I accidentally said beginAnimationsWithDuration and that beginAnimations has extra options, I meant animateWithDuration: in both of that.

Comment: and I am adopting your approach, but I will investigate the nested [UIView beginAnimation:..] (in my spare time). :)